# Tire gem - Does it support document boosting?

Tags: ruby, tire

Reading the ElasticSearch documentation (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/boost-field.html) it says that you can boost a document based on a value, is this behaviour implemented via Tire - I'm struggling with syntax if it is.

Update:

It looks like;

```
 mapping do                                                                                                             
  indexes :llt_code,            :index    => :not_analyze
  indexes :llt_name,            :analyzer => 'snowball'
  indexes :_boost,              :as => '_boost'
 end
```

is what I need, assuming the _boost column has the boosted value in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always worth checking what `YourModel.mapping_to_hash` outputs: this is what tire will send over to elasticsearch when it creates the mapping. As it is, your code is wrong - _boost  is a top level option, whereas what you've posted sticks stuff in the properties part of the mapping

```
mapping(:_boost => {:name => 'foo', :null_value => 1.0}) do
  indexes ...
end
```

should tell elasticsearch to use the field named `foo` for _boost this at the right level.